# How to use a guard in vue to ignore the route rule?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How to use a guard to move to next rule of route instead of redirect to specific route?

for example, I have some routes:

```
 routes: [
   { path: '/', component: Main },
   { path: '/about', component: About },
   { path: '/:product', component: Product },
   { path: '*', component: NotFoundException }
 ]
```

and in Product component I have `beforeRouteEnter` function like that:

```
 beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
   const question = checkIfExist(to.params.product);
   if (question) { next(); return;}

   next();
 }
```

if the product not exist then it should be redirect to NotFoundException component. in the stackoverflow example I see only example with redirect to specific url (like login) which is not helpful.

When I given url: '/some' then vue check if:

1. is / ? no => next route.
2. is /about ? no => next route.
3. is /:product ?  no => next route.
4. display NotFoundException component.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve ? .Please do clarify the objective

Comment: If the product does not exist then it SHOULD be '/' which is your home component

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the next route by route name.

First, name your exception route

```
 routes: [
   { path: '/', component: Main },
   { path: '/about', component: About },
   { path: '/:product', component: Product },
   { path: '*', name: 'notFound', component: NotFoundException }
 ]
```

Then, create a variable which stores your beforeEnter Logic

```
const productExists = (to, from, next) => {
   const question = checkIfExist(to.params.product);
   if (question) { next(); return;}
   next({
      name: "notFound"
   });
}
```

Add the route guard to the routes that you want to guard

```
 routes: [
   { path: '/', component: Main },
   { path: '/about', component: About },
   { path: '/:product', component: Product, beforeEnter: productExists },
   { path: '*', name: 'notFound', component: NotFoundException }
 ]
```